# How do I unclog a drain that had too much baking soda put in it?

Tags: plumbing

I have an old double basin sink that I haven't used for years. I did put a lot of baking soda in it to prevent smells. The faucet was accidently dripping into the sink without me realizing it was clogged until it overflowed. It was totally clogged. First I tried Instant Power Heavy Duty Drain Cleaner in it overnight, then added boiling water, both basins full. I tried a plunger and a wire coat hanger. It was still totally clogged. I scooped out as much of this mess as I could and added just straight vinegar, because that is when I read that too much baking soda can dry into a cement like plug. This sat for a few days, not doing anything. Then it was gone - drained away. I ran water in it to see if it was really cleared, but it was clogged again. Maybe just loosened the clog a little. So, I scooped out all the vinegar again and poured another half a gallon of vinegar into both sides of the basin. This time I heard it sizzling/bubbling. After a while, it completely drained again. I think it is cleared. I don't want to try the water in case it isn't cleared, but I was wondering if I should run hot water or any water in it to rinse any leftover vinegar out of the p-trap. I don't need this sink. I just don't want some mess in my lines that might be eating away at the pipes or something else. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Just boiling-hot water, repeated as needed, should finish the job. Poking with a drain augur such as [these examples](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Plumbing-Tools-Drain-Cleaning-Tools-Drain-Snakes/N-5yc1vZbqoe), or just a length of wire or plastic, might speed up the process, but is not needed.

Baking soda may lump together, but it remains soluble in water... eventually. Watching bubble in vinegar might be entertaining, but neither hurt nor helped get rid of the blockage. No worry, likely neither the sodium bicarb, nor the treatments you've tried, have done any permanent harm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!